# swift refresh control fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: swift, xcode6

I'm working with tableview controller and try to add pull refresh features but i'm having unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value error when test the pull to refresh feature in my iPhone 5. The error happen at connectionDidFinishLoading function.

```
    class FixtureTableTableViewController: UITableViewController,UITableViewDelegate,NSURLConnectionDelegate {
    var fixtures:[Fixture] = []
    var data = NSMutableData()
    var jsonResults:NSArray! = nil

       override func viewDidLoad() {
        println("view did load")
        super.viewDidLoad()

        connectToServer();

        self.refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
        //self.refreshControl?.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "pull to refresh")
        self.refreshControl?.addTarget(self, action: Selector("refresh"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)




        //self.fixtures = Fixture().listAll()

        // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
        // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

        // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
        // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()
    }

    func refresh(){
        println("refresh table")
        fixtures = []
        connectToServer()
        self.refreshControl?.endRefreshing()

    }

    func connectToServer(){
        println("connect to server")
        let plist = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("hijaukuningapp",ofType: "plist")
        let dict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: plist!)

        var serverURL = dict["serverURL"] as String

        println("server url \(serverURL)")
        let urlPath:String = serverURL + "mobileFixture/list"
        println(urlPath)
        var url = NSURL(string: urlPath)
        var request = NSURLRequest(URL: url)
        var connect = NSURLConnection(request: request, delegate: self, startImmediately: true)
        connect.start()
    }
    func connection(connection: NSURLConnection, didReceiveData _data: NSData!){
        println("receivedata")
        data.appendData(_data)
        println("end append data")
    }
    func connectionDidFinishLoading(connection: NSURLConnection){
        println("finished loading data\(data)")
        var err: NSError
        // throwing an error on the line below (can't figure out where the error message is)
        jsonResults = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as NSArray
        println(jsonResults)
        fixtures = Fixture().listAll(jsonResults)
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        println("viewWillAppear")
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)


    }
    /*
    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        //startConnection();
        println(jsonResults)
        for result : AnyObject in jsonResults {
            //println(result)
            if let fixture = result as? Dictionary<String,AnyObject>{
                var fixtureID = fixture["day"]
                println(fixtureID)
                var monthNamne = fixture["monthname"]
                var tempFixture = Fixture()
                tempFixture.day = fixtureID as String
                tempFixture.month = monthNamne as String

                var f2 = Fixture()
                f2.homeTeam="KELANTAN"
                f2.awayTeam = "KEDAH"
                f2.venue = "STADIUM SULTAN MOHAMED, ALOR SETAR"
                f2.day = "13"
                f2.month = "OCT"
                f2.time = "2045"

                fixtures.append(f2)
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
            println(fixtures.count)
        }
    }
*/
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
        // Return the number of sections.
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView?, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete method implementation.
        // Return the number of rows in the section.
        return fixtures.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("myCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as FixtureTableViewCell
        cell.lblVenue.text = fixtures[indexPath.row].venue
        cell.lblHome.text = fixtures[indexPath.row].homeTeam.name
        cell.lblAway.text = fixtures[indexPath.row].awayTeam.name
        cell.lblDay.text = fixtures[indexPath.row].day
        cell.lblMonth.text = fixtures[indexPath.row].month
        cell.lblTime.text = fixtures[indexPath.row].time

        var code:String = fixtures[indexPath.row].homeTeam.code + ".png"
        var awayCode:String = fixtures[indexPath.row].awayTeam.code + ".png"

        cell.homeLogo.image = UIImage(named: code);
        cell.awayLogo.image = UIImage(named: awayCode)

        return cell
    }


    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        println("indexpat " )
            }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
        println("prepare for sergues")
        var detailController:FixtureDetailViewController = segue.destinationViewController as FixtureDetailViewController

        var indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()
        detailController.fixture = fixtures[indexPath!.row]
    }



    /*
    // Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> Bool {
        // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
        return true
    }
    */

    /*
    // Override to support editing the table view.
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) {
        if editingStyle == .Delete {
            // Delete the row from the data source
            tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
        } else if editingStyle == .Insert {
            // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
        }    
    }
    */

    /*
    // Override to support rearranging the table view.
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, moveRowAtIndexPath fromIndexPath: NSIndexPath!, toIndexPath: NSIndexPath!) {

    }
    */

    /*
    // Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, canMoveRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> Bool {
        // Return NO if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
        return true
    }
    */

    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject!) {
        // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */

}
```

Answer (score 1):

In this line your data object is nil.

```
jsonResults = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as NSArray
```

Fix it by doing:

```
if let d = data {
        //Only executed if data isn't nil
        jsonResults = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(d, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as NSArray
}
```

In swift, an optional value means that it could be nil. If you don't get the actual value out of the optional, your code won't compile. The pattern above will only execute the code if the value is not nil.